# How to increase BatchSize with Tensorflow's C++ API?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow

I took the code in https://gist.github.com/kyrs/9adf86366e9e4f04addb (which takes an opencv cv::Mat image as input and converts it to tensor) and I use it to label images with the  model **inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb** stated in the Tensorflow tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition#usage_with_the_c_api). Everything worked fine when using a batchsize of 1. However, when I increase the batchsize to 2 (or greater), the size of 
**finalOutput** (which is of type std::vector) is zero.

Here's the code to reproduce the error:

```
// Only for VisualStudio
#define COMPILER_MSVC
#define NOMINMAX

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/env.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"

int batchSize = 2;
int height = 299;
int width = 299;
int depth = 3;

int mean = 0;
int stdev = 255;

// Set image paths
cv::String pathFilenameImg1 = "D:/IMGS/grace_hopper.jpg";
cv::String pathFilenameImg2 = "D:/IMGS/lenna.jpg";

// Set model paths
std::string graphFile = "D:/Tensorflow/models/inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb";
std::string labelfile = "D:/Tensorflow/models/imagenet_slim_labels.txt";
std::string InputName = "input";
std::string OutputName = "InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1";


void read_prepare_image(cv::String pathImg, cv::Mat &imgPrepared) {

       // Read Color image:
       cv::Mat imgBGR = cv::imread(pathImg);

       // Now we resize the image to fit Model's expected sizes:
       cv::Size s(height, width);
       cv::Mat imgResized;
       cv::resize(imgBGR, imgResized, s, 0, 0, cv::INTER_CUBIC);

       // Convert the image to float and normalize data:
       imgResized.convertTo(imgPrepared, CV_32FC1);
       imgPrepared = imgPrepared - mean;
       imgPrepared = imgPrepared / stdev;

}

int main()
{
       // Read and prepare images using OpenCV:
       cv::Mat img1, img2;
       read_prepare_image(pathFilenameImg1, img1);
       read_prepare_image(pathFilenameImg2, img2);

       // creating a Tensor for storing the data
       tensorflow::Tensor input_tensor(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape({ batchSize, height, width, depth }));
       auto input_tensor_mapped = input_tensor.tensor<float, 4>();

       // Copy images data into the tensor:
       for (int b = 0; b < batchSize; ++b) {

             const float * source_data;

             if (b == 0) 
                    source_data = (float*)img1.data;
             else 
                    source_data = (float*)img2.data;

             for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {

                    const float* source_row = source_data + (y * width * depth);
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {

                           const float* source_pixel = source_row + (x * depth);
                           const float* source_B = source_pixel + 0;
                           const float* source_G = source_pixel + 1;
                           const float* source_R = source_pixel + 2;

                           input_tensor_mapped(b, y, x, 0) = *source_R;
                           input_tensor_mapped(b, y, x, 1) = *source_G;
                           input_tensor_mapped(b, y, x, 2) = *source_B;

                    }
             }
       }

       // Load the graph:
       tensorflow::GraphDef graph_def;
       ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), graphFile, &graph_def);

       // create a session with the graph
       std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session> session_inception(tensorflow::NewSession(tensorflow::SessionOptions()));
       session_inception->Create(graph_def);

       // run the loaded graph 
       std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> finalOutput;
       session_inception->Run({ { InputName,input_tensor } }, { OutputName }, {}, &finalOutput);

       // Get Top 5 classes:
       std::cerr << "final output size = " << finalOutput.size() << std::endl;
       tensorflow::Tensor output = std::move(finalOutput.at(0));
       auto scores = output.flat<float>();
       std::cerr << "scores size=" << scores.size() << std::endl;

       std::ifstream label(labelfile);
       std::string line;

       std::vector<std::pair<float, std::string>> sorted;

       for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= 1000; ++i) {
             std::getline(label, line);
             sorted.emplace_back(scores(i), line);
       }

       std::sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end());
       std::reverse(sorted.begin(), sorted.end());
       std::cout << "size of the sorted file is " << sorted.size() << std::endl;
       for (unsigned int i = 0; i< 5; ++i)
             std::cout << "The output of the current graph has category  " << sorted[i].second << " with probability " << sorted[i].first << std::endl;

}
```

Do I miss anything? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the graph in the protobuf file had a fixed batch size of 1 and I was only changing the shape of the input, not the graph. The graph has to accept a variable batch size by setting the shape to (None, width, heihgt, channels). This is done when you freeze the graph. Since the graph we have is already frozen, there is no way to change the batch size at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. When I changed to the model used in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/benchmark (differente version of inception) bigger batch sizes work correctly.

Notice you need to change the input size from 299,299,3 to 224,224,3 and the input and output layer names to: input:0 and output:0

Comment: Yes, probably this other model was frozen with a variable batch size and the one I was testing it was not. Thanks!